# How can I get more coal?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm running out of fuel and need some coal. I have no trees and I don't want to waste the little wood I have left. How can I find more?

Comment: Mod-recommendation questions are off-topic here, much like questions asking for game recommendations or shopping advice.  Sorry.  You should ask in the chat though, there's some frequent Minecraft players in there most of the time.

Comment: I'd recommend re-wording this so that it's more along the lines of, "How can I acquire more coal?", so that it doesn't automatically assume a mod is required.  A mod can be given as an answer, but it shouldn't be required.

Comment: Just dig. If you're low on torches, re-use them by backtracking and breaking some so that you can reuse them and keep digging. Consider blocking off any dark parts of the tunnel behind you so that monsters don't spawn where they can reach you.

Comment: @young guilo if your low on coal i recommend planting trees and using charcoal instead. its a renewable (unlimited) resource, unlike coal.

Comment: @GnomeSlice Actually, [we don't have a blanket ban on mod-rec questions anymore](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/is-mod-rec-really-am-umbrella-category-that-we-want-to-use-or-is-it-confusing).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. **How can you get more coal?**

   - You can burn Wood to make Charcoal (Don't confuse with coal), but **you can also harvest coal from Coal ore blocks**.
     Coal ore is a block common in almost all maps and elevation, you can easily found them by digging.

   > "Just dig" - SevenSidedDie
2. **You are running out of fuel?**

   - If you are using it in powered minecarts, Coal and Charcoal are the only option, otherwise if it's for a furnace, Coal is not the only source of fuel. Coal is the 3rd most efficient fuel but you can use also almost any type of Wood, Blaze Rods and Lava Buckets to fuel it, being the Blaze Rods and Lava Buckets the 2nd and 1st most efficient fuels.
3. **You are running out of trees?**

   - When cutting trees clean also the foliage, it gives you Saplings that you can use for reforest some areas or simply plant where the trees was.
     Saplings grow on dirt or grass blocks, and can grow into a tree if provided by light and air above them.

   > "I recommend planting trees" - Ender

Charcoal is very slightly different from Coal. It cannot be used for crafting the upcoming coal block, and does not stack with coal.

Comment: Using lava buckets as fuel also returns you the bucket, so it is pretty efficient if you are near lava (underground or in the Nether)

Comment: Also although it rarely happens, lava lakes can appear on the surface

Answer (score 0):

If you need coal for furnaces, build a [blaze spawner farm](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nrtcJ4c_6oQ) in the nether, and use blaze rods.

If you need coal for coal blocks for building, build a wither skeleton farm in the nether.  Note, this is significantly more difficult than a blaze farm.  No good tutorials, but [wither skeleton farm science](http://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_56957&feature=iv&src_vid=3S5JQYxp0ek&v=RcQzqk_8OTo) is necessary.

Comment: Can you direct me to a site where I can learn how to make one?